# PHP Registration Script, Inserting to Database not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue with my PHP code for a registration form on my website. Some of the code doesn't get executed when the form is submitted.

```
if ($fnameError = "" && $emailError = "" && $userError = "" && $passError = "" && $cpassError = "" && $tickError = "") {
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","login")or die("Can't connect to database");

    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $name = $_POST['fname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $pwd = crypt('$pass', '$user');
    $pwd = md5($pwd);
    $tblname = "users";
    $flp="INSERT INTO $tblname (Name, Username, Password, Email Address)
        VALUES
        ('$name','$user','$pass','$email')";
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $flp)or die("Can't insert to table");
    if ($res) {
        $complete = "Registered successfully please log in to continue";
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }       
}
```

Everything works fine until it gets to the line starting $flp="INSERT INTO...

Can anyone assist in helping me debug this code, also, please don't link to already written code I want to be able to use this code.

EDIT:

I changed a line to purposely cause an error so I know PHP is reading the line and it does give me the syntax error for the line starting $res=mysqli_...

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$res' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\XamppNew\htdocs\site\regusr.php on line 85"

I removed the semi-colon at the end of the Insert line just to get the error.

EDIT:

I've managed to isolate the problem to the start of the if statement. It seems to be that the line doesn't treat each error as having no content. However, if the error exists it will be displayed on the page next to the form and no such error gets displayed.

Comment: What error do you get.?

Comment: **Danger**: You **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)**.

Comment: you have space between column name "Email Address". is this correct?

Comment: @User016, I don't get any errors, it just doesn't work.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi, yes, the space is there on my database.

Comment: @Georgewb13 just use backticks in `Email Address` field, it will work :)

Comment: @SumitBijvani, backticks aren't working. It seems to ignore anything past the line starting $flp = "INSERT INTO...

Comment: @Quentin, I added code to decrease possible injection attacks but the form is not meant for online use it's just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

//if ($fnameError = "" && $emailError = "" && $userError = "" && $passError = "" && $cpassError = "" && $tickError = "")
//{
    // Connect to DB
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "login");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    // Parse Input
    $user = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
    $pass = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
    $pwd = md5(crypt('$pass', '$user'));
    $name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
    $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

    // Insert Record
    if ($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO users (`Name`, `Username`, `Password`, `Email Address`) VALUES ('$name', '$user', '$pwd', '$email')")) {
        printf ("New user has id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);
    } else {
        printf("Failed to insert row: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    }

    // Close DB Connection
    $mysqli->close();
//}

?>
```

Comment: Still nothing. The check is blocking it but it shouldn't be as the errors are empty.

Comment: Add this above the `if` block: `var_dump($fnameError); var_dump($emailError); var_dump($userError); var_dump($passError); var_dump($cpassError); var_dump($tickError);` what is the output?

Comment: I commented out the if statement at the beginning and it gives me "Failed to insert row". So it's checking it.

Comment: I get: string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" after the var_dump.

Comment: i've updated my answer, can you try that? If the insert is failing, it will throw an error and from that error message we can solve your problem.

Comment: We have fixed it. The ID wasn't set to auto increment and the if statement was using "=" instead of "==".

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote (with backticks) your column name `Email Address` since it has a space in it.

Comment: That isn't working, still getting nothing from the PHP in terms of database submission and nothing shows in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks in `Email Address` field because it has space.

```
$flp="INSERT INTO $tblname (`Name`, `Username`, `Password`, `Email Address`)
```

Comment: I copied the entire line and it still isn't giving me any feedback, no errors, no submission, it seems like it is ignoring the code.

Comment: The block executes as I can echo the password from within the block, scratch that, the password has stopped echoing.

Comment: echo the insert query and then directly execute it in phpmyadmin.. check its working or not

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..........
       $flp="INSERT INTO $tblname (Name, Username, Password, EmailAddress)
        VALUES
        ('".$name."','".$user."','".$pass."','".$email."')";

Comment: Email Address is supposed to have a space in it. So it won't work.